# C# Generics Instantiation

Tags: c#, generics

All, I have a method that returns a List. This method is used to return the parameters of SQL StoredProcedures, Views and Functions depending on name. What I want to do is create a list of objects and return this list to the caller. The method is below

```
private List<T> GetInputParameters<T>(string spFunViewName)
{
    string strSql = String.Format(
        "SELECT PARAMETER_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS " +
        "WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = '{0}' AND PARAMETER_MODE = 'IN';",
        spFunViewName);
    List<string[]> paramInfoList = new List<string[]>();
    DataTable paramDt = Utilities.DTFromDB(conn, "InputParmaters", strSql);
    if (paramDt != null)
    {
        Converter<DataRow, string[]> rowConverter =
            new Converter<DataRow, string[]>(Utilities.RowColConvert);
        paramInfoList = Utilities.ConvertRowsToList<string[]>(paramDt, rowConverter);
    }
    else
        return null;

    // Build the input parameter list.
    List<T> paramList = new List<T>();
    foreach (string[] paramInfo in paramInfoList)
    {
        T t = new T(paramInfo[NAME], paramInfo[TYPE], Convert.ToInt32(paramInfo[CHARMAXLEN]));
        columnList.Add(column);
    }
    return columnList;   
}
```

I *clearly* can't instantiate `T` via `new` and pass to the constructor, but it should be clear what I am attempting to do. Is there a way to do what I want with out three additional methods?

Note. The main issue is that the number of parameters I am passing to T can either be two **OR** three.

Thanks for your time.

*Edit: The `struct`s I use are as follows*

```
public struct Database
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public List<Table> tables { get; set; }
    public List<StoredProcedure> sps { get; set; }
    public List<Function> funcs { get; set; }
    public List<View> views { get; set; }
    public Database(string name, string filename)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.filename = filename;
    }
}

protected internal struct StoredProcedure
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string[]> parameters { get; set; }
    public StoredProcedure(string name, List<string[]> parameters)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}

protected internal struct Function
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string output { get; set; }
    public List<string[]> parameters { get; set; }
    public Function(string name, string output, List<string[]> parameters)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.output = output;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}

protected internal struct View
{
    public string name {get; set;} 
    public List<string[]> parameters { get; set; }
    public View(string name, List<string[]> parameters)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

Comment: What *is* the type of `T` likely to be here?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, It is actually a `struct`. I am attempting to build a reusable tree structure to show databases, tables etc. but I also want to be able to use the information obtained from this procedure again - so I use a singleton pattern with `struct StoredProcedure`, `struct Function` etc. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose `"InputParmaters"` is a typo?

Comment: The problem I have is that I have spent so many years writing FORTRAN that I often find it hard to see what the best OOP approach is...

Comment: @Killercam: But a parameter *isn't* a stored procedure, nor is it a function. Why don't you have *one type* to represent parameters, and then use that with *composition* for stored procedures etc. It's not clear where the singleton pattern comes in, but I'd strongly avoid it if I were you... and the idea of a singleton *struct* makes no sense to start with :(

Comment: To follow Jon Skeet, you could put a generic constraint so that `T` will always support a constructor you would like to use. Or, if it is always the same struct, just make it a `list<yourStructName>`

Comment: @Jon Skeet, sorry, that was not clear. I only want to perform this operation once, so I have a class that build the tree info and holds onto it - rebuilding only if I dispose the singleton. Within this class I have structs that define the attributes (table, their columns, sps, functions, and view (along with their parameters)). functions have both input and output parameters, views and sps do not...

Comment: @Killercam: But you haven't shown what you'd want T (which represents a parameter as far as I can see) to be. Oh, and those structs look like they should *really* be classes.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for your time here. `T` in this case will be either of the `struct`s above (either `StoredProcedure`, `Function` or `View`). Why in this case should they be classes - I thought seeing as I am creating the database object only once this would be fine. However, I can see that this could hold a fair bit of information...

Comment: @Killercam: But you're creating an instance of T for each *parameter*, which isn't right if T is a StoredProcedure or Function, is it? As for why these should be classes - read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet, your right, I don't need to do that - the loop is redundent. But I still have the problem that the constructor for T can either have two OR three parameters. I will read that article thanks for the reference. I hope the new book sales are going well...

Comment: @Killercam: I don't see that you've got a problem at all. Your method is meant to return the *parameters*, so get it to do that. The caller can then construct the StoredProcedure/Function/whatever. Try to avoid doing too much in a single method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Activator` class to create `T` and pass the parameters.

```
Type type = typeof(T);
var result = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { yourParameters });
```

Used in your code snippet:

```
T t = Activator.CreateInstance(type, colInfo[NAME], colInfo[TYPE], Convert.ToInt32(colInfo[CHARMAXLEN]));
```

Comment: @Killercam No problem. However as other have written it is best to avoid this and use a different designed appproach.

Comment: At this stage I am not sure why? Can you humour me? I have three types, sps, functions and views. tow of these have input parameters only (sp and views), functions have both...

Comment: Well, i've read now that you use structs. However you could search or create a superclass with the constructor and put it as a constraint on T. Then you don't have to use the activator.

Comment: Sorry about this. This seems new to me. Are you saying to wrap the multiple structs in a single class and use that?

Comment: Better to post an example of the kind of structs you have in the question ;). For now I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 3):

I'm neither endorsing nor detracting this technique, but you can use:

```
(T) Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(T), colInfo[TYPE], Convert.ToInt32(colInfo[CHARMAXLEN]) );
```

I think I'd rather have separate factory methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance()` as other mentioned or pass a delegate  `Func<string, string, int, T>` avoiding the reflection overhead .

```
 List<T> GetInputParameters<T>(string spFunViewName, Func<string, string, int, T> itemCreator)
 {

    ....
    List<T> paramList = new List<T>();     
    foreach (string[] paramInfo in paramInfoList)     
    {         
       T t = itemCreator(paramInfo[NAME], paramInfo[TYPE], 
            Convert.ToInt32(paramInfo[CHARMAXLEN]));         
      paramList.Add(t);     
    }     

    return columnList;    
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I clearly can't instansiate T via new and pass to the constructor

As written, no; however, you *can* if you constrain your type parameter to only accept types with constructors:

```
private List<T> GetInputParameters<T>(string spFunViewName) where T : new()
{
    // your code here
}
```

In the example above you would be able to say:

```
T myItem = new T();
```

In your specific case, it looks like you expect each of the generic types to share something in common.  Consider also constraining the type with an interface:

```
private List<T> GetInputParameters<T>(string spFunViewName) where T : new(), ISomeInterface
{
    // your code here
}
```

That would allow you to, after you instantiate you object, apply values to any properties on the interface:

```
T myItem = new T();

myItem.SomeProperty = somevalue;
myItem.AnotherProperty = anothervalue;
```

For more info, check out [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN for more info on generic type constraints.

Comment: I like this alot! But doesn't the fact that the objects inside my three structs is different mean I cannot use an interface as it is all or nothing?

Comment: Ideally, in this case, each of the structs (or classes) would be able to implement (or inherit from) the same interface or base class, if nothing else, just something with a factory method.  Would you be able to update your question to include the actual structs?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use List<[DbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)>

That is a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(int));
constructor.Invoke(colInfo[NAME], colInfo[TYPE], Convert.ToInt32(colInfo[CHARMAXLEN]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create generic database parameters (and connections and commands, etc) with ADO.NET [DbProviderFactories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda6c36e).

> The System.Data.Common namespace provides classes for creating
>   DbProviderFactory instances to work with specific data sources. When
>   you create a DbProviderFactory instance and pass it information about
>   the data provider, the DbProviderFactory can determine the correct,
>   strongly typed connection object to return based on the information it
>   has been provided.

In your code, you could create a `DbProviderFactory` and then call [`CreateParameter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.createparameter).

```
string providerName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ProviderName;
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
DbParameter parameter = factory.CreateParameter();
```